# iTunes connect architecture issue during validation

Tags: ios, validation, architecture, xcode4, app-store-connect

Im going to submit an app, but when validating I get an error:

```
   The following issues were found during validation:
  iPhone application executable is missing a required architecture
```

[image: problem validating]

I have searched and found that I need to set
Build only architecture only 
in build settings/ architecture

well this is in no [unchecked??], also tried with YES, but not working either.

[image]

Also would i have to add armv6 in Architectures?? [even when in valid architectures i have v6 and v7??]
how to do it?
when i go to add one, it just gives me a blank space to type, what to type to include it?, in case this is what i need??

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using a beta version of XCode. Revert to a standard release and try again. Apple don't allow submissions from beta versions.